# Which word is the odd one out?

Tags: word, odd-one-out

Which of these words is the odd one out? Please give a reason too.

```
BAP, DEW, LOP, OIK, RED, SAW, SEW, WAS, WED, ERF, KIO, MNB
```

Comment: I am voting to reopen as I have another answer I would like to share; otherwise, I would put it in a comment :D **Edit:** Stuff it, I am putting it in a comment. (ROT13) Gur bqq bar bhg vf FRJ orpnhfr vg vf gur bayl jbeq gung qbrf abg pbagnva yrggref jvgu n pybfrq ybbc (r.t. O, Q, B, C nyy unir pybfrq ybbcf, ohg F naq R naq J qb abg).

Comment: @user477343 You can answer now! The question isn't closed and I can change the accepted answer.

Comment: It doesn't allow me to, for some reason :\

Comment: No, it is not the accepting of an answer that disrupts this, because I have answered many questions before after an answer was accepted; it just does not have the "Your Answer" option below the page (when I scroll down through all the answers) :|

Comment: @user477343 Oh sorry.. I didn't see it had been put on hold! That's a shame.

Comment: Hahah, no problem. I believe we need $5$ people to vote for reopening so it is not put on hold anymore...? I can't be certain, but am pretty sure :P

Comment: So @Anush it seems you don't actually know what the correct answer is?

Comment: @DanielP I do know the official answer but if someone comes up with another clever solution  that's always great. Official isn't always best :)

Comment: @Anush Accepting an answer and then modifying the question to invalidate said answer is plain wrong.

Comment: Oh no I didn't mean to do that!!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There may be more than one connection, but one odd-one-out is:

> BAP

If the rule is the common words form a

> connected path on a QWERTY keyboard.

Comment: This is a nice answer.

Comment: @Anush Well is it correct? If it isn't this truly is too broad... even if it is it's still quite broad.

Comment: I think this is more bread than broad.

Comment: Wait? How are MNP connected on a QWERTY keyboard?

Comment: This is really odd. This answer was accepted and then the question was changed which invalidates the already accepted answer.

Comment: @DanielP That was just my mistake. I fixed it.

Answer (score 7):

> OIK because it's the only one that starts with a vowel.

Comment: Actually, this could work too as the question is quite broad :D

Comment: @KevinL I disagree. That's wouldn't make an interesting puzzle.

Comment: Well, whether the puzzle is interesting or not, this is qualifies as a correct answer I believe :D @Anush

Answer (score 6):

One possible answer is

> SEW is the only word in the list that doesn't contain any closed loops anywhere in the word like in the letters A,B,D,O,P,R which are letters present in the all of the other words.

Comment: Even after the edit, yours is still alive!

Comment: And my answer survived even the since [deleted edit with `MNP`](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/posts/71798/revisions).  That said, `WES` or `JIK` would probably be the best addition to rule out my answer, assuming Tom's answer was desired.

Answer (score 5):

I’m thinking it’s

> OIK, because it’s the only one with 2 vowels.

Comment: That would be a terrible puzzle! :)

Comment: @Anush if this is incorrect, is it possible to add another three letters which disproves my answer? Otherwise it might be too broad!

Comment: Assuming the other answer is on the right track, ERE, KOI, EWE etc.